# is there any greedy or DP algorithm to solve a problem

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

Array $A[1..m]$ from integer is given. subsequence $A[a..b]$ is called subsequence if $A[a]$ to $A[b]$ is $>0$. what is the minimum number of these subsequence is in any given array?

Comment: Where did this question come from?

Answer (score 2):

Here's hint for starting the problem:  find the interval which covers $A[1]$.  You should be able to find it in $O(n)$ and prove that there is no better interval containing $A[1]$.

After that, suppose the interval was $(1, r)$.  Then find an interval $(c, d)$ with $c \le r+1$, one which has to be in an optimal solution containing what's already been found. You should be able to find it in $O(n^2)$ time and prove its optimality.

Continuing in this way gives an $O(n^3)$ algorithm.  It can be reduced to $O(n^2)$ by , once you find the optimal $(c, \_)$ don't bother checking that $c$ again.

It can be reduced to $O(n \log n)$ in a complex way by first computing an array $M$, where $M[k] = j$ means

- $(k, j)$ is a positive interval
- there is no positive interval $(k, l)$ with $j < l$

but start by first working out the $O(n^3)$ and then the $O(n^2)$ solution.

DP just means not repeating redundant calculations by recording them.  I think you shouldn't try solving a problem by asking about "DP".  Just solve the problem as best you can, then eliminate redundant calculations either by recording them or skipping them.  If you want to call it DP then do so, or if you don't then don't.  Technically a prefix sum array is DP but no one calls it that.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For each positive interval $i,\dots,j$, let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether that positive interval is selected.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j}$ subject to
$$\sum_{i,j: i\le k \le j} x_{i,j} \ge 1 \quad \text{for all positive elements $k$}$$
This is a *set covering* problem.

---

Alternatively, you can solve this as a shortest path problem in a directed acyclic graph defined as follows. The node set is $$N=\{i\in\{1,\dots,n\}: A[i]>0\}\cup\{n+1\}.$$ Directed arc $(i,j)$ corresponds to positive interval $[i,k]$, where $k$ is the largest positive node $<j$. The problem is to find a shortest path from the smallest node to the sink node $n+1$. Because the graph is acyclic, you can find a shortest path in one (forward or backward) pass. The usual Bellman’s equation yields a dynamic programming recursion.

In the example, the nodes are
$$\{1,3,4,7,8,9,11,14,16\},$$
the arcs are
$$\{(1,3),(1,4),(1,7),(3,4),(3,7),(4,7),(7,8),(7,9),(7,11),(7,16),(8,9),(8,11),(9,11),(11,14),(11,16),(14,16)\},$$
and a shortest path from $1$ to $16$ consists of arcs $(1,7)$ and $(7,16)$.

Comment: excellent, exactly you are the god of math. is it possible to make it more simpler via an example ? +1.

Comment: integer programming is np-complete, which is worse than n^2. And I'm not even sure how the shortest paths solution would work since state is essential here. the path we took to get to the node matters. in order for a node to fully encapsulate state, you would need something like n^2 nodes.

Comment: @ScottHahn I provided an explicit example to help illustrate.  The node set has cardinality $1$ more than the number of positive elements, so at most $n+1$.

Comment: ah, I see, my mistake. so essentially the nodes in the final path are the splits. I think that works then, in O(n^2) runtime as well.

Comment: No, the graph has a node for each positive element, plus a sink node. For the example, I recommend actually drawing the nodes and arcs to help see what’s going on.

Comment: @RobPratt in my example graph is ${1,2,3,4,6,8}$? pardon me I couldent get the point ! how you extract nodes from given array (for example my array)?

Comment: No, I listed the nodes in my answer.  They are the $i$ indices where $A[i]>0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot my last question is, would you please a bit more clearer about arcs? why (1,16) for example not include in edge set?

Comment: For $(i,j)=(1,16)$, we have $k=14$ as the largest positive node $<j$. But $[i,k]=[1,14]$ is not a positive interval, so the arc $(1,16)$ is not included.

Answer (score 0):

First, we can precompute the value for each interval in O(n^2) time and save those values. Then:

OPT(i,j):

Trim negative values off the head and tail of this interval.
Denote the new begin/end indices as i_trimmed and j_trimmed.

Return 1 if [i_trimmed,j_trimmed] is a positive interval (using the precomputed values).

Else, return min ( OPT(i_trimmed,k) + OPT(k+1,j_trimmed) ) for all i_trimmed <= k < j_trimmed.

Finally, compute OPT for all the size 1 intervals, then size 2 intervals, etc... up to n. Should be O(n^2) time.

The algorithm should be correct by construction. If we can cover all the positive numbers with 1 interval, then it always returns 1. If not, then there must be a split somewhere. And we consider all possible splits.